# RegExp in js example needed

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract this "SD" from text "SouthDacota (SD)" in Javascript. I am newbie to regex in js and wanted to know if any one has any ideas.

Comment: @8GB, Do go through some regex tutorials. Big part of utilizing regular expressions is to understand your data range as well as what you want to accomplish. Will `(<letter><letter>)` always be your format? Will it always be at the end of the string? Will it be 2 and only 2 letters? Or are you simply matching the letters SD inside of paranthesis? ...

Comment: `/(SD)/`, `/(sD)/i`, `/\((SD)\)/`, `/(SD)\)$/`, `/^.+\((SD)\)$/` will all match your situation but what is best? This is what I mean.

Comment: @ Ben Swinburne I used this "\((\w{2})?\)" donest help though. @cbayram basically the text can change what I need is to extract whats inside of "()".

Comment: @8GB Then what m.buettner gave you should suffice. Only changes I'd make is to make it case-insensitive and not make the parentheses part of the match. `/\(([A-Z]{2})\)/i`

Comment: @cbayram and m.buettner Thanks.

Comment: You could also use \w, `/\((\w{2})\)/i` as you originally did, but \w matches letters, digits and underscores

Comment: @cbayaram: yes I want to match anything inside braces. So thanks, will use this one instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest regex would match the parentheses, and in between two upper-case letters. In addition you can "capture" the two letters (with unescaped parentheses), so you can retrieve them without the parentheses:

```
var regex = /\(([A-Z]{2})\)/;
var matches = inputString.match(regex);
var stateCode = matches[1];
```

But you should really read up [on some basics](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: This could also be shortened to `var stateCode = /\([A-Z]{2}\)/.exec(input)[1];`

Comment: And there's more than [one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) good tool out there that let's you immediately test what you are doing.

Comment: @Beardy yes, but for beginner questions I prefer the unoptimized versions that tell a bit more about the workings of the code.

Comment: @m.buettner, good answer, given the question you should match the "SD" and not "(SD)" though

Comment: @cbayram sorry I forgot the capturing parentheses when copying the code from Chrome's developer tools ;).